# In Sublime Text 3, how can I change the comment character?

Tags: sublimetext3, roxygen2

I like the auto-comment feature `Ctrl + /`, but I'd like to be able the change the character it uses arbitrarily. I have read many similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986285/how-can-i-toggle-xml-line-comment-in-sublime-text-3), but it's not exactly a generic solution.

How can I make the comment character use something different? The specific use case is that I'm writing R code and using Roxygen2 for documentation. This uses `#'` as the comment character, instead of just `#`. So I I'd like to set sublime to use `#'` because as is, I can't use it for Roxygen2 comments.

Questions regarding Sublime2, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239767/enable-automatic-commenting-in-sublime-text-for-a-custom-syntax), refer to '.tmPreferences' files, but I have not been able to find any such files in my Sublime 3 installation.  If the answer is still these files, where are they stored in Sublime 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable automatic commenting in Sublime Text for a custom syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239767/enable-automatic-commenting-in-sublime-text-for-a-custom-syntax)

Comment: I think that must be referring to ST2 -- do tmPreferences files exist in ST3? Where are they on a linux system?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in [Enable automatic commenting in Sublime Text for a custom syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239767/enable-automatic-commenting-in-sublime-text-for-a-custom-syntax), [`.tmPreferences` files are used to specify what the comment markers are for a syntax](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/comments.html#md-comments-shellvariables).

To edit the comment markers for R:

1. Install [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit)
2. Open the command palette
3. Type `OA:OR`
4. Select `OverrideAudit: Open Resource`
5. Select `R`
6. Select `Comments.tmPreferences`
7. Edit the [`TM_COMMENT_START` value](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/61bfd68ea07a3aede68cd6a65c80be702b3d6db8/R/Comments.tmPreferences#L16) to `#'` as desired
8. Save the file
9. Use the toggle comment functionality on an R file and see that it now uses `#'` instead of `#`

Comment: Thanks! That worked! It was impossible to find this information anywhere, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Gold! `ini` comments using semi-colon have been bothering me for ages!

Comment: Thanks! I was pleasantly surprised that when you save the file it will automatically save it in your custom Packages directory (instead of overriding the build-in R package). Also, for my needs, it made more sense to add `#'` as an additional `TM_COMMENT_START_2` rather than overriding the default. This makes roxygen blocks play nice with Wrap Plus, but I can still use either method depending on where I am at in my code.

Comment: Life saver! Worked like a charm.

Comment: WHAT A NINJA. Keith wins the internet